# How can I deal with the file which users upload?

Tags: database, web

If I have a website, and every user can upload his or her file, after I get this file, how can I deal with this file.

Should I store it to a specific folder(like `upload`), and store the file path in a specific database(for example table upload_file)?

Or should I just store this file in the database, if I can, how can I apply this to reality??

I think the first way is much better, but can I store all upload files in the same folder, or should I make a folder for each user?

Maybe I can encrypt the file name with md5 or anothers?
I do not know in real website development, how can you deal with the file, and keep the relationship with the user?

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: First question - do you need to access or share files outside of your web/db application? If yes, then storing files into folders is needed. Otherwise I would prefer database approach - but that depends on other constraints, eg how much you pay for file vs database storage. Nevertheless this question is outside of SO scope :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are small, just store it in the database;
Otherwise store they in a floder